# org.restlet: Posting JSON content against webservice returns HTTP error 411 (length required)

Tags: web-services, json, post, java, restlet-2.0

Simplified code example: http://pastebin.com/9ZQxSXi9

Hi

I wanted to experiment with the restlet 2.0 library and the gpodder webservice but somehow i reached a point where I can't see the wood for the trees.
The service in the example requires HTTP authentication and to post some JSON content to a URL. 
Nothing that complicated but somehow even though the debug view claims the request object to contain the necessary content the RESTful webservice's response leads me to believe the HTTP header of the request was missing the content.

Any ideas on what's the reason? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that none of the implementation of WriterRepresentation I've seen (JsonRepresentation, JacksonRepresentation, XStreamRepresentation) set the size of the representation when an object is passed. So if you create a new JacksonRepresentation(map) the size is not calculated.

You have to compute manually the length of the map content and calling Representation.setSize(). 
Or, as I did, use a

new JsonRepresentation(" a json string... ");

This constructor is able to compute the size, of course, that's the string length, so the proper content-length header is set and everything works smooth.