# Length Required (411) - Length Required in a RESTlet client

Tags: java, httpclient, restlet-2.0

Im new to REST and am developing a client to post data to a external hosted service. Im using org.reslet.resource.ClientResource to create a client

```
    Representation rep = new JsonRepresentation(json);
    rep.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    rep.setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);

    ClientResource clientResource = getClientResource();
    Representation reply = clientResource.post(rep);
    return readResponseStream(reply, clientResource);
```

however I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" Length Required (411) - Length Required
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:858)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1197)
at org.mine.client.impl.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:59)
```

The same code works for a get request

```
Representation reply = clientResource.get();
```

I'm using reslet api 2.0.8. This seems like the problem in post [org.restlet: Posting JSON content against webservice returns HTTP error 411 (length required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678962/org-restlet-posting-json-content-against-webservice-returns-http-error-411-leng)

I have the following jars in the classpath

```
org.apache.commons.codec.jar org.apache.commons.logging.jar org.apache.httpclient.jar org.apache.httpcore.jar org.json.jar org.restlet.ext.json.jar org.restlet.jar
```

Any help would be  greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're on Windows, try running Fiddler while making the request.  This is especially helpful if you have another working call to compare it to.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that GAE doesn't support HTTP chunked encoding, therefore serialized object can't be sent (via POST or PUT) to a GAE server.
In Restlet Framework version 2.1 M4 we have a workaround available that buffers the HTTP entity to prevent chunk encoding. To use it, call the ClientResource#setRequestEntityBuffering(boolean) method with a "true" value. Note that this workaround isn't required for the GWT edition.

As you are using Restlet 2.0.8, I suggest you use the workaround published here : http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1219

Best regards,
Thierry Boileau

Comment: The same appens on Cloudbees, thanks for the trick (https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/20889467-error-411-length-required)

Comment: @Martin That's because Cloudbees is a Google partner that runs off AppEngine: https://cloud.google.com/partners/. 

Wow this answer was so specific! AppEngine wasn't even mentioned but it was the correct solution!